# Proving that there exists some delta that meets a requirement?

Tags: analysis

So my analysis class just started in the continuous functions portion of analysis. I have been struggling with proving that a function is continuous, but have been able to solve some of the problems with the epsilon delta method, at least I think I am. Then I came across a problem as follows.

Let $f: R -> R$ be a continuous function and suppose that for some $c$ in $R$ we have $f(c) > 0$. Prove that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) >$ 0 for all $x$ in $(c-\delta, c+\delta)$.

I barely know how to use epsilon delta let alone proving that some delta exists. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because $f$ is continuous, if we pick $\epsilon = f(c) - 0$, by definition of continuity, there must exist a $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$ for $x-\delta < x < c+ \delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By continuity there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x-c| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(c)| < f(c)/2$. If $f(c) > 0$, then $f > f(c)/2 > 0$ on $]c-\delta, c+\delta[$.